# Generating a video with FFmpeg starting from a sequence of PNG snapshot creates black video output

Tags: video, ffmpeg

When I generate a video starting from a sequence of PNG snapshots, the output video is black.

Here is a minimal working example: I generate the video from [these two frames](https://ufile.io/4vks9) with the following command on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and produces a black video MP4 file.

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -i frame%d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

Do you know a way around this?

I know that a similar question has been asked, for example, [here](https://superuser.com/questions/588766/converting-series-of-images-with-ffmpeg-results-in-black-video), but the solution does not solve the problem in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Some players don't like low framerate videos. The workaround is to set a high output rate.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -i frame%d.png -r 5 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
```

`5` should be enough, but try 10 if not.

Comment: I tried with -r 5, -r 10 and -r 20, and I still get a black video.

Comment: Your input is 4096x8192! Many players will refuse to play as that's compliant with a recently added H264 level. Downscale by adding `-vf scale=-2:1080,setsar=1` after the `-r 5`